# How to extract the parts of this string between escaped quotes?

Tags: regex, r

I would like to extract the quoted names from this string (a result of `deparse()`ing a call).

```
tstStr <- "!is.na(neb[[\"ba\"]]) & neb[[\"ba\"]] >= targ[[\"ba\"]] & neb[[\"ht\"]] >= 0"
```

So, the result would be `c("ba","ba","ba","ht")`.  I've tried various things with `gsub` and `grep` but can't get what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I'd use:

```
m <- gregexpr(pattern = '".*?"', tstStr)
gsub('"', '', regmatches(tstStr, m)[[1]])
# [1] "ba" "ba" "ba" "ht"
```

Comment: This works great, but why is the "?" necessary in the pattern?  I see that it does not work when I remove the "?", but I am not understanding why it is breaking.

Comment: `?` after `*` forces the regex engine to do a shortest match.

Comment: What @AvinashRaj said. The `?` makes the quantifier "lazy", "reluctant", "ungreedy", or "minimal". For some more explanation, [see here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), under the section titled "Laziness instead of Greediness". Greediness is the default behavior, so without a `?`, the pattern will match the longest available string that begins and ends with a `"`, which if you think about it is not what you generally want here.

Comment: Thanks, the default behavior is really counter-intuitive for me.

Comment: Maybe think of it this way: if `.*` always matched minimally, it would always match 0 characters, and `.+` would always match just one. At least in those cases, the default behavior is more like what you probably expect. (That said, I do know I went through the same initial puzzlement as you in cases like the one above.)

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(tstStr, perl('(?<=")[A-Za-z]+'))[[1]]
#[1] "ba" "ba" "ba" "ht"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `qdapRegex` function `rm_between` would work here.  `rm_between` extracts or removes content between a left and right bound:

```
tstStr <- "!is.na(neb[[\"ba\"]]) & neb[[\"ba\"]] >= targ[[\"ba\"]] & neb[[\"ht\"]] >= 0"

library(qdapRegex)

rm_between(tstStr, left='[["', right='"]]', extract=TRUE)


## [[1]]
## [1] "ba" "ba" "ba" "ht"
```